# Symfony client not updating result

Tags: symfony, client

In my code, I have URLs that I want to check with `\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client`

When I launch my test, I get500 Internal Server Errors. I check in my browser, I have 500 Internal Server Error also.
I fixed the issues, checked again with my script and still have the errors. But when I check again with my browser, everything works fine.

I tried to clear the cache, but I got the same problem.

Here's the code

```
public function testCheckUrl()
{
    $client = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
    $client->setServerParameters(array());
    $router = static::$container->get( 'router' );

    $successCodes = [200, 301, 302];
    $total = count(self::$allFullLocationsArray);
    $i = 0; //index
    $s = 0; //success
    $e = 0; //error
    $failUrls = array();

    echo PHP_EOL.'Checking '.$total.' URLs'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach (self::$allFullLocationsArray as $location)
    {
        $i++;
        $url = $router->generate( $location );
        $client->request( 'GET', $url );

        if (in_array($client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $successCodes)) {
            $s++;
        }else {
            $e++;
            $failUrls[$url] = $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
        }

        echo "[".number_format($i/$total*100, 2)."%] - Success: ".$s.", Failures: ".$e.($i < $total ? "\r" : PHP_EOL);
        flush();
        ob_flush();

    }
    $this->assertEquals(
        0,
        count($failUrls),
        (function($failUrls) {
            $ret = "";
            foreach ($failUrls as $url => $code)
            {
                $ret .= $url." => ".$code.PHP_EOL;
            }
            return $ret;
        })($failUrls)
    );
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the server's error log tell you about the errors?

Comment: Nothing, i check apache logs and symfony logs, i get nothing

Comment: Could it be that phpunit complains because of the additional output produced by echo?

Comment: I don't think so, I checked the page output and commented the line in the code where the crash occured. And my test pass. This line is an image, and the image url come from the database. But in my browser it works fine, the first time launched the test, the image path was wrong, i fixed it, and check in my browser that it works fine now. But in my test it still have a 500 error...

Comment: I dumped my object from the controller in my test and in my browser. It seems that in my test an old version of the object is used (v1) but in browser the new version is used (v2). Maybe the php cli use a cached version of my database ?